# IF/ELSE breaking logic of javascript and JSON interaction

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

Somehow, the way I've structured my if/else statements has caused this code to only work if the page_type_id / panel_type_ids are the same.

For the snippet below, it begins by working fine seeing that page_type_id is 2, it uses that logic to hide unnecessary divs, and then uses other statements to decide that the content for panel_type_id 2 goes to one div while panel_type_id 3 goes to another.

If all elements have the same page_type_id it works fine  but the iterations break somehow if it goes from page_type_id 2 to 1 or 3 and I can't figure out how.

The snippet below, on each iteration, should print:

```
left 93  right 93
Full Page
Full Page 2
Full Page 3
```

Here's the snippet

```js
const obj = [{
            "pageID": "93",
            "page_type_id": "2",
            "display_id": "2",
            "slide_order": null,
            "duration": "74",
            "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
            "panel_id": "86",
            "panel_type_id": "2",
            "cont_id": "138",
            "contID": "138",
            "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nLeft 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
        },
        {
            "pageID": "93",
            "page_type_id": "2",
            "display_id": "2",
            "slide_order": null,
            "duration": "74",
            "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
            "panel_id": "87",
            "panel_type_id": "3",
            "cont_id": "139",
            "contID": "139",
            "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nRight 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
        },
        {
            "pageID": "94",
            "page_type_id": "1",
            "display_id": "2",
            "slide_order": null,
            "duration": "74",
            "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
            "panel_id": "87",
            "panel_type_id": "1",
            "cont_id": "139",
            "contID": "139",
            "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nFull Page<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
        },
        {
            "pageID": "95",
            "page_type_id": "1",
            "display_id": "2",
            "slide_order": null,
            "duration": "74",
            "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
            "panel_id": "87",
            "panel_type_id": "1",
            "cont_id": "139",
            "contID": "139",
            "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nFull Page 2<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
        },
        {
            "pageID": "96",
            "page_type_id": "1",
            "display_id": "2",
            "slide_order": null,
            "duration": "74",
            "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
            "panel_id": "87",
            "panel_type_id": "1",
            "cont_id": "139",
            "contID": "139",
            "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nFull Page 3<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
        },
    ];
    
    let counter = 0;
    
    var fullContent = document.getElementById('fullContent');
    var leftContent = document.getElementById('leftContent');
    var rightContent = document.getElementById('rightContent');
    var topLeftContent = document.getElementById('topLeftContent');
    var topRightContent = document.getElementById('topRightContent');
    var bottomLeftContent = document.getElementById('bottomLeftContent');
    var bottomRightContent = document.getElementById('bottomRightContent');
    
    var fullColumn = document.getElementById('fullColumn');
    var leftColumn = document.getElementById('leftColumn');
    var rightColumn = document.getElementById('rightColumn');
    var leftColumnQtr = document.getElementById('leftColumnQtr');
    var rightColumnQtrHalf = document.getElementById('rightColumnQtrHalf');
    var rightColumnQtr = document.getElementById('rightColumnQtr');
    var leftColumnQtrHalf = document.getElementById('leftColumnQtrHalf');
    
    const pages_array = obj.reduce(function (pages_array, item, index, obj) {
        const current_pageID = item.pageID;
        const exisiting_page = pages_array.find(page => page.pageID === current_pageID);
    
        if (exisiting_page === undefined) {
            const new_Page = {
                pageID: current_pageID,
                content: [item]
            }
            pages_array.push(new_Page);
        } else {
            exisiting_page.content.push(item)
        }
    
        return pages_array;
    }, []);
    
    setInterval(() => {
        const currentJSONobject = pages_array[counter];
    
        fullContent.innerHTML = '';
        rightContent.innerHTML = '';
        leftContent.innerHTML = '';
        topLeftContent.innerHTML = '';
        topRightContent.innerHTML = '';
        bottomLeftContent.innerHTML = '';
        bottomRightContent.innerHTML = '';
    
        for (var i = 0; i < currentJSONobject.content.length; i++) {
    
            if (currentJSONobject.content[i].page_type_id == 1) {
    
                leftColumn.style.display = "none";
                rightColumn.style.display = "none";
                leftColumnQtr.style.display = "none";
                rightColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";
                rightColumnQtr.style.display = "none";
                leftColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";
    
                if (currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 1) {
                    fullContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].content;
                }
    
            } else if (currentJSONobject.content[i].page_type_id == 2) {
    
                fullColumn.style.display = "none";
                leftColumnQtr.style.display = "none";
                rightColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";
                rightColumnQtr.style.display = "none";
                leftColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";
    
                if (currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 2) {
                    leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].content;
                }
                if (currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 3) {
                    rightContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].content;
                }
    
            } 
    
        }
    
        console.log(pages_array[counter])
    
        counter += 1;
        if (counter === pages_array.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    
    }, 1500)
    console.log(obj);
```

```html
<div class="row middle" id="middle" style="background-image: url();">
        <!-- Full Page Divs -->
        <div class="col-lg-12" id="fullColumn">
            <div class="fullContent" id="fullContent" style="height: 100%; ">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Full Page Divs -->
    
        <!-- Half Page Divs -->
        <div class="col-lg-6 leftColumn" id="leftColumn">
    
            <div class="leftContent" id="leftContent" style=" height: 100%; ">
    
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-lg-6 rightColumn" id="rightColumn">
    
            <div class="rightContent" id="rightContent" style=" height: 100%; ">
    
            </div>
    
        </div>
        <!-- End Half Page Divs -->
    
 
    </div>
    <!-- End Row Middle -->
```

Comment: Why do you have the 'rightContent' and 'leftContent' twice in html?

Comment: Please reduce this to a **minimal** case to reproduce the error.

Comment: In order the community can help you as recommended by Jared Smith tries to reduce the problem to the minimum case. Eliminates the noise of unnecessary matters. if you think this information is necessary, add a https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codesandbox.io, etc to facilitate the cooperation of the community.

Comment: Thanks @JaredSmith, I've reduced it and turned it to a snippet now. not sure why the snippet was removed before

Answer (score 1):

In order to simplify your code why don't you extract the logic in the `for loop` in a function and inside that function use `switch` instead of this crazy `if/else if/else`.

```
for(var i = 0; i < currentJSONobject.content.length; i++){
    myFn(currentJSONobject, index)
}

function myFn(jsonObj, index) {
    switch (jsonObj.content[index].page_type_id ) {
        case 1:
            //...<logic for id 1>
        break;
        case 2:
            //...<logic for id 2>
        break:
        default:
        //... etc
    }
}
```

Once you simplify you code a little bit it might become easier to pinpoint where the issue is.

Comment: So how do I set the page_type_id in the switch? And will I also be able to set the content by panel_type_id, because I'm doing this with nested if/else statements

Comment: OH wait I see, case 1 is for page_type_id 1 and inside that I can do the if/else for my panel_type_ids

Comment: One other question: Will this reset at each iteration? So if it moves from element with page id of1 to page id of 2, will it call this switch each time?

Comment: You logic is in a `for loop` so it would go through the switch on each increment of `i` just like it was with the if/else before.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was thinking. maybe this will help though as far as moving from one page type to another

Comment: I'm trying to implement this but it says index is not defined. Can you work this into the code I actually have already? All this does is simplify my logic but it creates another problem now because I can't get the console to load properly